# In WebSphere data source definitions, does JDBC driver property connectionTimeout override data source settings

Tags: db2, websphere, datasource, connection-timeout

we are using WebSphere datasources to manage our database connections. A sample datasource definition from our server.xml looks like this:

```
<dataSource id="dev_ate" jndiName="database/dev_ate"
    jdbcDriverRef="db2_driver" type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <connectionManager maxIdleTime="30m"
        **connectionTimeout="30s"** />
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="xxx"
        serverName="aaa.bbb.ccc" portNumber="yyy"
        securityMechanism="7" user="uuu"
        password="ppp"
        retrieveMessagesFromServerOnGetMessage="true" sslConnection="true"
        clientProgramName="abc" driverType="4" encryptionAlgorithm="2"
        **connectionTimeout="60s"**
        sslTrustStoreLocation="${DB2CERTS}" />
</dataSource>
```

Does the connectionTimeout attribute in properties.db2.jcc has the same effect as the one in connectionManager? If so, which one is used? If not, what is the difference?

Any response would be appreciated!

Thx
Christian

Answer (score 2):

The two `connectionTimeout` properties do not override each other.  They actually have different meanings.  The DB2 JCC driver property `connectionTimeout`, which is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/java/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052038.html), and relates to connecting to the database.  The `connectionTimeout` property of `connectionManager` is a timeout on a connection becoming available from the connection pool. It should be noted that it is possible for you to wait for a portion of the `connectionTimeout` of the `connectionManager`, after which a non-matching connection becomes available in the pool. The connection manager will close the non-matching connection and request a new one from the DB2 JCC driver, after which the full `connectionTimeout` of the DB2 JCC driver will apply, even if that exceeds the remaining amount of time on the `connectionTimeout` of the `connectionManager`.  The two timeouts are independent of each other.